# Multiple Queries into 1 Query doing counts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, union

Ok, trying to make this make sense and see if I can do this.  I have multiple queries stored in SQL Server 2012 that I can run individually to get actual results.  Each of these queries connect to a multitude of tables.  What I want to do is take all of these queries and put them into a single query to get counts in one master list.

So for example.  I have a query that looks for all records that have no email addresses.  The next query looks for all records missing a phone number in a set field.  The next query looks for records missing a filled field.

Each of these queries pull back results and I can run them one at a time.  I want to set myself up a single query I can run to give me counts on each in a single results list.

I started doing a Union statement and put two of the query codes into it.  The results came up like this:

```
NoEmail   NoPhone
NULL      24486
74596     NULL
```

What I would like this to look like is this:

```
NoEmail     NoPhone
74596       24486
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

I hope this is enough info and if not, let me know and I'll get you more.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

Set up (for demonstration purposes only, so you can see the data I'm using):

```
create table t1 (
  id numeric,
  email varchar(20)
);

insert into t1 values (1,'test@example.com');
insert into t1 (id) values (2);
insert into t1 (id) values (3);

create table t2 (
  id numeric,
  phone varchar(20)
);

insert into t2 values (1,'123-456-7890');
insert into t2 (id) values (2);
insert into t2 (id) values (3);
insert into t2 (id) values (4);
insert into t2 (id) values (5);
```

Query:

```
select 
(select count(id) from t1 where email is null) as NoEmail,
(select count(id) from t2 where phone is null) as NoPhone;
```

Result:

```
NoEmail NoPhone
2       4
```

You can add as many additional queries on to the end of the query as you'd like:

```
select 
(select count(id) from t1 where email is null) as NoEmail,
(select count(id) from t2 where phone is null) as NoPhone,
(select ...) as anotherCol,
(select ...) as yetAnotherCol;
```

Comment: Ok, so this code pretty much takes the data that is already in a table and moves it to a new table to count and then you combine tables.  Correct me if I am wrong.

I have the data in tables and I have the data in stored views.  I want to have all the queries run in a single view that I can set to email me the contents once a day.  I can deal with the formatting of multiple rows but would prefer it all to be on one row if I could.

Comment: @Jayson, no, you just need to run the query.  I show some Set Up just to show the data I was using.  No tables are created.  It's just a select statement that uses subqueries.

Comment: Ah ok, my mistake.  Thanks for clarifying.  Let me try that and see what happens.  Thanks for the info